# iOS remote notification:How to play the alert sound customed by user in iOS client while not decide by the apns argument ('sound')

Tags: ios, notifications, push

iOS remote notification:How to play the alert sound customed by user in iOS client while not decide by the apns argument ('sound') ?

I don't want to tell the backend which sound file was chosen by the user

Can I convert the remote notification to local notification?

Comment: Maybe. If your app hasn't been terminated then you can use a silent push and convert that to a local notification in your app delegate

Comment: thank you for your comment, have to admit that the requirement is a little eggache.